# Find number of files in folder and sub folders?

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find the total count of the number of files under a folder and all its sub folders.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Maybe something like this will do the trick:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

Try the command from the parent folder.

- `find . -name <pattern> -type f` finds all `f`iles in the current folder (`.`) and its subfolders.
- `-name <pattern>` only looks for certain files that match the specified pattern. The match is case-sensitive. If you need the match to be case-insensitive, use `-iname` instead.
- The result (a list of files found) is passed (`|`) to `wc -l` which counts the number of `l`ines.

Comment: The solution will fail on files which names contain a newline.

Comment: @user unknown: `find . -type f -ls | wc -l`

Comment: even faster: `find . -type f -print0 | tr -d -c '\0' | wc -c`

Comment: @arrange: even faster: `find . -type f -printf . | wc -c` - I adopt the print for my solution instead of my -exec echo .

Comment: Be aware that this also counts hidden files starting with a dot. I consider this a feature rather than a bug, but it is good to know.

Answer (score 34):

Use the `tree` command. You might need to install the `tree` package.

It will list all the files and folders under the given folder and list a summary at the end.

Answer (score 24):

To count files (even files without an extension) at the root of the current directory, use:

```
ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l
```

To count files (even files without an extension) *recursively* from the root of the current directory, use:

```
ls -lR | grep ^- | wc -l
```

Comment: Those will not count hidden files.

Comment: True. I'm more inclined to accept and use your answer as the solution.

Comment: Actually, not counting hidden files / files in hidden directories is an useful _feature_ while working inside a subversion or git repository!

Comment: And this is very slow on large folders because `ls -l` will sort the output.

Answer (score 20):

The fastest and easiest way, is to use `tree`. Its speed is limited by your output terminal, so if you pipe the result to `tail -1`, you'll get immediate result. You can also control to what directory level you like the results, using the `-L` option. For colorized output, use `-C`. For example:

```
$ tree share/some/directory/ | tail -1
558 directories, 853 files

$ tree -L 2 share/some/directory/ | tail -1
120 directories, 3 files
```

If it's not already there, you can get it [here](ftp://mama.indstate.edu/linux/tree/).

Answer (score 13):

```
find -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

Don't count the output lines of find, because filenames, containing 99 newlines, will count as 100 files.

Comment: Filenames containing new lines is an incredibly rare edge case.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: So an error will be extremely hard to find.

Comment: I like a good edge case, especially many years later.

Answer (score 6):

Use this command for each folder in the path

```
for D in *; do echo $D; find $D -type f| wc -l; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find . | wc -l`

`find .` will list all files and folders and theire contents starting in your current folder.
`wc -l` counts the results of find

Comment: This solution counts also the folders, I gave the mark cause it matched my occasion that I didnt want to count them in :)

Comment: The solution will fail on files which names contain a newline.

Answer (score 1):

find seems to be quicker than tree so I used below to count files in each directory of the current working directory (ignoring files in CWD) with allowing directories to have spaces:

`ls -d */ | while read dir_line
 do
     echo -n "$dir_line :"
     find "$dir_line" -type f | wc -l
 done`

Comment: Parsing output of `ls` is [very bad idea.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Great code, how can I arrange the output lines say in an increasing or decreasing count of files

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this option myself:

> ls -alR | grep -c ^-

Comment: Please add some details ...