# How to count number of files in a directory but not recursively

Tags: command-line

Simple question I'm sure.  I've seen [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34099/find-number-of-files-in-folder-and-sub-folders) that show how to do it including subdirectories, but I want to know how many files (not folders) are in the current directory only.  Thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
ls -F |grep -v / | wc -l
```

1. `ls -F` list all files and append indicator (one of */=>@|) to
   entries
2. `grep -v /` keep all de strings that do **not** contain a
   slash
3. `wc -l` count lines

Comment: List of everything except directories.

Comment: I really appreciate you breaking it out and explaining the sections, thank you for a working and well explained answer!

Comment: While all answers solve my problem, I'm choosing this one as its documented and easiest for me to understand. But thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 26):

Try this oneliner:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: This is good, only files and nothing else :-)

Comment: This skips links and special character devices.

Comment: All answers here work great!  So first, THANK YOU.  Second... how do I choose?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
ls -al | grep ^[-] | wc -l
```

1. `ls -al` --
   list all file with long listing format
2. `grep ^[-]` -- search for string which start with "-" that is symbol for denote regular file when list file with ls -al
3. `wc -l`     -- count lines

Comment: What about soft links? What about hard linked files?

Comment: Nice one, only files and links, nothing else.

Comment: For soft/hard link jut replace `-` by `l`

Comment: I really appreciate you breaking it out and explaining the sections, thank you for a working and well explained answer!

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add [thom's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/370721/622020) because I like to play with [Bash](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html). Here it goes:

`echo "Directory $(pwd) has $(ls -F |grep -v / | wc -l) files"`

Bellow is an example result of my `/data` directory:

`Directory /data has 580569 file(s).`

And bellow are my explanations:

1. `echo double-quoted-message` will print a desirable message.
2. `$(any-desirable-valid-command)` inside the double quoted message of an `echo` will print the result of related command execution.
3. `pwd` will print the current directory.
4. `ls -F` is for listing all files and append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries. I copied this from [thom's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/370721/622020).
5. `grep -v /` is a command for searching plain-text, the `-v /` parameter will keep all the strings that do not contain slash(es).
6. `wc -l` will print line counting.

I know this question is 3 years old, I just can't hold my urge to add another answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `tree` installed on your system you can use this command:

```
tree -L 1 /path/to/your/directory | tail -n 1
```

It shows you the number of files and directories in that directory.

`-L n` shows the depth of search.

You can install `tree` with `sudo apt-get install tree`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash, no pipes, no subshells, no external executables:

```
_c() { printf '%d\n' $#; }
_c *
_c *.sh
```

Will fail with error if there are no (matching) files, which bash can avoid with shopt -s nullglob.

Answer (score -3):

To count total number of files with specific extension you may type:

```
ls|grep jpg |wc -l
```