# How to display number of items in sub-directories from command line

Tags: command-line, files, filesystem, directory, ls

In Ubuntu graphical user-interface, I can list the sub-directories in a directory where one column represents the number of items in these sub-directories. As shown here:

[image: nautilus screenshot]

Is there a way to get the same result (number of items in size column) using the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-determine-the-total-size-of-a-directory-folder-from-the-command-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find number of files in folder and sub folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34099/find-number-of-files-in-folder-and-sub-folders)

Comment: @PerlDuck Again misunderstood, I am not looking for the total number of files. I want it to display like in a GUI. The number of items for each sub-directory in one go. Please see the updated image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little shell function that you can use. Just add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
lsc(){
    ## globs that don't match should expand to a null string
  shopt -s nullglob
  ## If no arguments were given use the current dir
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    targets="."
  ## Otherwise, use whatever was given
  else
    targets=($@)
  fi
  ## iterate over the arguments given
  for target in "${targets[@]}"; do
    ## get the contents of the target
    contents=("$target"/*)
    ## iterate over the contents
    for thing in "${contents[@]}";  do
      ## If this one is a directory
      if [[ -d "$thing" ]]; then
        ## collect the directory's contents
        count=("$thing"/*)
        ## Print the dir's name (with a '/' at the end)
        ## and the number of items found in it
        printf "%s/ (%s)\n" "$thing" "${#count[@]}"
      else
        ## If this isn't a dir, just print the name
        printf "%s\n" "$thing"
      fi
    done
  done
}
```

then open a new terminal and run:

```
lsc /path/to/dir
```

For example, given the following directory (the `\012` are newlines in the names):

```
$ tree
.
├── a bad one
│   └── file 1
├── a bad worse\012one
│   └── file 1 \012two
├── dir1
│   └── file
├── dir2
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── dir3
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
├── dir4
│   └── dir
├── empty_dir

8 directories, 7 files
```

You would get:

```
$ lsc 
./a bad one/ (1)
./a bad worse
one/ (1)
./dir1/ (1)
./dir2/ (2)
./dir3/ (3)
./dir4/ (1)
./empty_dir/ (0)
./mp3/ (1)
```

The main advantages of this approach are:

1. You can run it on multiple directories:

   ```
   lsc /path/to/dir /path/to/dir2 ... /path/to/dirN
   ```

   Or on the current one:

   ```
   lsc
   ```
2. It can work on arbitrary file and directory names, even those containing spaces or newline characters as you can see above.